# Dexing fails due to duplicate definitions: is there a way to fix while retaining 2 versions of a library?

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management, dex

I have these dependencies defined for my app:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1'
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.3.1'
    compile 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1'
    compile 'com.hp.mss:mobileprintsdk:v2.02.418'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
         transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `mobileprintsdk` depends on Android Support v4 `22.2.1` while I want to use `25.0.1`, as shown in this dependency tree:

```
release
+--- LOCAL: xmpcore.jar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.1
|    +--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.0.1.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.0.1.jar
+--- com.hp.mss:mobileprintsdk:v2.02.418
|    +--- com.android.support:design:22.2.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1
|    |    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-22.2.1.jar
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-22.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-22.2.1.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-22.2.1.jar
\--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.2
     |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.14
     |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10
     |    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
     |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10
     |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
     \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
```

Is there any way to get gradle to put the older version in a different package so that dexing can complete?

Comment: Have you tried excluding v4 like so: compile 'com.hp.mss:mobileprintsdk:v2.02.418{ exclude group: com.android.support, module: support-v4}

Comment: You can use the "jarjar" tool to move all classes in one of the libraries to a different package.